# NumberFormatException while running the project in NetBeans

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

I am a bit new to servlets, and I am using **NetBeans**, I have a servlet that accepts a number from the user and prints it multiplication table.
I have `TableServlet.java` as follows-->

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
public class TableServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String s=request.getParameter("t1");
        int x= Integer.parseInt(s);
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            out.println(x+"x"+i+"="+i*x);
        }
        out.close();
    }    
}
```

I have `newhtml.html` as follows-->

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="TableServlet" method="get">
            Enter any number
            <input type="text" name="t1" />
            <input type="submit" value="GetTable"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's getting successfully deployed, but no output is found on the browser after running this project..
Instead, i can see only this on my browser-->

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Please mapped your servlet like this: @WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/TestServlet"})

Comment: @MasudCSECUET that is not related to the issue. Obviously the servlet is correctly mapped to an URL

Comment: Srinivas, log the value of `s` and check if it is really a String representing an integer.

Comment: **note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.** And ... did you look in the logs to see exactly what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is most likely thrown by this line:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

and the cause is that the value of `s` is not a valid integer.

Indeed, this message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

tells us that the value of `s` is `null`!  And that implies that the request being processed does not have a `"t1"` parameter.  I can't immediately see what is causing that, but the prime suspect is the HTML form.

Here are a couple of ideas:

- Try composing a request URL in your browser's URL bar.
- Use your browser's web debugger to see what request URL is being sent to the server when you use your form.